# Cached map performance when view ArcGIS Server map services in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, performance, map-service

ArcGIS server cached map service that displays at the following scales:

1:20,000
1:10,000
1:5,000
1:1,000

Refresh takes 1 second when using the Javascript/silverlight viewer, but 4-7 seconds when consuming the service in ArcGIS Desktop.

Any thoughts to as why this might be?

Comment: Is your dataframe projection the same as the cached map service projection?

Answer (score 3):

The quotation from the Esri documentation (as mentioned from John) is [correct](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0053000000p9000000).

The resolution to avoid the overhead in ArcMap havign to do this resampling, is to

- go to your scale settings in ArcMap.
- Load your cache tiling levels from the service thats in your TOC.
- Click the tickbox to 'only display these scales when zooming'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a request is made for a tile at a scale that exactly matches a scale level in the cache, the map service returns the tile directly. Most often, requests do not exactly match the scale levels in the cache. In this situation, ArcMap generally requests the tile from the next closest scale level and resamples it to match the requested scale. ArcMap has the ability to blend and label multilayer cache tiles on the client side (unlike Web ADF applications).

Comment: This appears to be a quotation from the ESRI docs: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0053000000p9000000